# Incorrect output for selection sort on linked list

Tags: java

Im having trouble with my linked list selection sort below:

```
public static void selectionSort(LN l) {
    for (LN r = l; r != null; r = r.next) {
        LN min = r;
        for (LN s = r; s != null; s = s.next)
            if (min.value > s.value)
                min = s;
        LN temp = r;
        r.value = min.value;
        min.value = temp.value;
    }
}
```

So for the input: 10, 4,6,2,1,7,9,8,5,3
I get the output: 1,1,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3

What's wrong with the sort here?

Comment: whats wrong with a `while` loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This:

```
        LN temp = r;
        r.value = min.value;
        min.value = temp.value;
```

is wrong. By setting `temp` equal to `r`, you're actually causing them to refer to the same object; so modifying `r.value` is equivalent to modifying `temp.value`. So the above ends up not really modifying `min.value`; it just sets `min.value` to what it already was.

Instead, you should write:

```
        int temp = r.value;
        r.value = min.value;
        min.value = temp;
```

Comment: Can't the OP use getters/setters for this?

Comment: @siebz0r: Getters are normally written so as to be equivalent to the underlying field, and setters so as to be equivalent to assignment to it. `r.setValue(min.getValue())` and `min.setValue(temp.getValue())` would not really change anything. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: Wouldn't a setter set by value instead of by reference and thus solving the problem?

Comment: @siebz0r: Sorry, no. You seem to be confused about how values and references work in Java. :-/